# Extract a single file from a zip in Ruby

Tags: ruby, zip, archive

I'm needing to extract a single file from a zip archive.  The following worked at one point, then stopped.  I've tried re=writing it a few times from scratch in the most basic way, yet it still can't find the file I'm searching for.

```
def restore(file)
    #pulls specified file from last commit
    found = []
    #files.each do |file|
        print "Restoring #{file}"
        puts
        Zip::ZipFile.open(".fuzz/commits/#{last_commit}.zip") do |zip_file|
            zip_file.each do |f|

                if f == file.strip
                    if File.exists?(file)
                        FileUtils.mv(file, "#{file}.temp")
                    end

                    FileUtils.cp(f, Dir.pwd)
                    found << file

                    if File.exists?("#{file}.temp")
                        FileUtils.rm_rf("#{file}.temp")
                    end
                else
                    puts "#{file} is not #{f}" #added this to make sure that 'file' was being read correctly and matched correctly.
                end
            end
        end
        print "\r"
        if found.empty? == false
            puts "#{found} restored."
        else
            puts "No files were restored"
        end

    #end
end
```

The "#{file} is not #{f} shows both files, yet continues to think there is no match.  I've scratched my brain for the past day over it.  I'm hoping I've just gone stupid and am missing an obvious flaw/typo.

Comment: It looks like `if f == file.strip` never produces True. Try to add debug prints like `puts "#{f}" ; puts "#{file.strip}"` just before the `if`.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that, and it shows the same file name for both.  Just tried again to double check, but still doesn't find a match.

Comment: By the way, the ZipFile class has no method `each`.

Comment: @Linuxios, not sure what you mean by your first comment, and I modeled this from [link]http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2011/12/using-ruby-and-zip-library-to-compress-directories-and-read-single-file-from-compressed-collection/ which uses an `each` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you quote as your example has one big difference:

It's not `f ==` but rather `"#{f}"==`. This basically is a cryptic way of saying `f.to_s`, which means `f` isn't a string, but that it's to_s method returns the name of the file. So, try replacing this:

```
if f == file.strip
```

With this:

```
if f.to_s == file.strip
```

Comment: So both you and @Sergey Bolgov fixed it!  Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few experiments, and found that `f == file.strip` does not work:

However, both of these works:

```
if f.name == file.strip

if f.to_s == file.strip
```

I personally prefer `f.name` because it makes code easier to read and understand.

Comment: I would recommend you to use `f.name`. I expresses your intentions clearer.